# Problems in first android/java tutorial

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am just getting started attempting to learn Eclipse with Java for Android programming. In fact, I'm working on the first basic sample app in the tutorial at developer.android.com. I have the following activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
       android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and the following strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"? >
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">My First App2</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_display_message">My Message</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

</resources>
```

As you can see I have a button_send string and an edit_message string in strings.xml which are both referenced in activity_main.xml. However, a build yields the error "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/button_send')". Any ideas, please?

Comment: Where is the directory structure of your `res` dir and where are the files located?

Comment: Its some trivial thing if `edit_message` can be found. Try saving the files. Cleaning the project. Or adding a new `View` and new `String`. It maybe some whites-pace character.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple ideas:

1. Make sure strings.xml is in your res/values folder.
2. Clean your project (Project->Clean).  This will delete your gen folder and re-generate it.  Any time you make a change to your resources, it's a good idea to clean the project and regenerate all of the R.id.* values.

EDIT:

You can also go into the eclipse GUI for the XML file and right-click the button.  Click "Edit Text", which should bring up your String values.  You should be able to see button_send.  If you don't, there's an issue with your strings.xml.

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

You have an extra > in the second to last line of the opening to your `LinearLayout`. Remove that character, clean your project, and that will probably fix the problem.

Comment: Yep, if that's not a typo or a copy/paste error, the 2nd > is probably what's causing the issues.  Good catch!